# How to fix .htaccess properly laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, deployment, cpanel

Im trying to deploy a laravel project into server. Im getting this common error

> is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I was dd everything for like 4 hours! dd in route/web.php is working! in public_html>index.php is not working this

```
    $response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

And Im thinking that .htaccess is not okay, I dont know anymore
.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Comment: I fixed that by deleting bootstrap/cache/config.php file